# ckeditor execCommand dialog not showing

Tags: ckeditor

I created a dialog in `ckeditor`.

```
    editor.ui.addButton('blublu',
            {
                label: 'blublu',
                command: 'blublu',
                icon: this.path + 'icons/blublu.png'
            }
    );
    editor.addCommand('blublu', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('blublu'));

    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'blublu', this.path + 'dialogs/dialog.js' );
```

If I press the button the dialog shows, everything is fine. Now I try to open this window from another dialog :

```
( function() {
    CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'templates', function( editor ) {
        return {
            title: editor.lang.templates.title,
            contents: [...],
            onHide: function(){
                if(condition)
                    //dostufff;
                this.hide();
                editor.execCommand('blublu');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It works the first time the editor is loaded. But if I open the dialog from the button in the `toolbar`, and I close it, I can't open the dialog from the 'templates' dialog. I have the **dark background** as if a dialog where shown, except the dialog, is not there. It is hidden and just shows it is not enough because all buttons handlers on it don't work.

I have no error in console.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I've tested it with existing plugins and it looks like you need to call execCommand asynchronously with `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout( function() {
    execCommand( commandName );
} );
```

If fix doesn't work for every browser, then you will have to add some short delay. I don't see better solution.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. finally I triggered the click on the button that launched the dialog I wanted to